# Increasing TdrDelay from 2s to 30s in Registy Editor for GPU solved Device Lost error in my Vulkan Program. What can be the cause for it?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

My Vulkan program is giving me a Device Lost error. I added TdrDelay in the registry editor from 2s to 30s. Now my program works fine. What could be the reason for it? Considering that I cannot post the code here, what could be the possible reason that I can check and improve my program further?

Comment: My guess would be exceeding the 2 s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows initiates a TDR when the GPU doesn't respond within a given period.  It assumes that the GPU is hung.  In your case, this can also happen if you give it a single submission that takes a long time to process.

One common way this could happen is in compute pipelines where there is a lot of data.  There may be nothing "wrong" with the workload, other than it taking too long.  I think that the fix would be to split the computation into a number of smaller submissions.

Another explanation would be a bug in a shader in either a graphics or compute pipeline that causes excessive looping or doing too much work.  This seems unlikely for a graphics pipe because such a problem could impact getting frames onto a visible screen, which would be pretty noticeable.

A more unlikely possibility is some sort of synchronization error where something in Vulkan is deadlocked waiting on something.  But this would tend to get stuck forever and not just for a few seconds.

But if your program has some large compute workloads, I'd suspect that first.

Comment: What a great answer, you were right, I had large compute workloads and when I divide the work into different command buffers & submit it to the queue, the issue disappeared. Thanks!!